# Make numpy uniform more uniform

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, distribution, uniform-distribution

I need to generate a set of 10^5 data points that when binned into a histogram the fit to the data is a horizontal line.
Using np.random.uniform is not uniform enough (see plot). Any ideas on how to make a uniform distribution more uniform and not so random???

[image]

Comment: `numpy.linspace(-3, 3, 100000)`?  How much more uniform than your existing code do you want?  Can you quantify it?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what the histogram bins will be?

Comment: Thanks! I combined linspace with random.uniform and got what I needed, which was basically prove with a statistical test that the distribution of the data was almost the same as the distribution of the horizontal line (over >95% probability that they are the same distribution)

Answer (score 6):

It's *random*--of course it won't match a perfect uniform distribution exactly.  The variance should be small, and decrease reciprocally as you increase the number of samples.  If you *do* want an exact uniform distribution with a finite number of samples, then you don't have a uniform distribution any more; you have a permutation, which you can generate with [numpy.random.permutation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html).

It's difficult to find definitive information, but I think NumPy's default generator is based on a Mersenne Twister RNG, which has *excellent* statistical properties.  So again, the problem is not that these samples aren't uniform.  E.g., have a look [at the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) for a histogram that looks just like yours.

Comment: Yes, numpy does indeed use the Mersenne Twister (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState)).